# Library to parse and display e-mails (from files in a maildir directory, to build my own e-mail client)

Tags: open-source, library, email, email-client, email-attachments

I'd like to build an e-mail client. I'm interested in building the GUI (folders, list of e-mails, account setup, …) but I don't want to deal with parsing MIME e-mails and displaying HTML e-mails securely.

I'm looking for a library that would e.g. take as an input:

- **the contents of a maildir file**
- or alternatively just the MIME part of that file (I can parse the headers easily)

The library should **return a list of attachments**.

The library should also provide **a widget to display the contents of an HTML e-mail**, securely (e.g. disable loading external images by default, disable scripts…).

[image]

Preferences:

- open-source, non-GPL (my code is CC0)
- compatible with the Qt toolkit (other toolkits / web are okay too)

I assume that a library doing the display is likely to be able to handle attachments too, but those could be separate libraries.